# Export data from a list view using a button

Tags: export-to-excel, export-to-csv, admin-on-rest

I am building a simple admin-on-rest application. One of the features is the user to export the content from a list view. So far I have two possible approaches in mind.

- Export based on the selected filters (my favorite).
- Export based on the selected rows from the table using check boxes.

I guess two things are necessary to achieve that:

- Be able to render a button somewhere in "list view": would be great to add an "export" button inside the "filters" section. I couldn't find a way to render an "export" button keeping the filters.
- That "export" button would be able to get the filters (from the list view filter section) for creating my custom URL for downloading the data. Or if using check boxes, detect the selected rows from the table and export that data.

I have been looking for examples or following other colleagues questions and I coundn't come up with anything similar. Any info/example/project will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

This is quite solvable. The filter is stored in the redux form and can be accessed by any connected component. I am guessing you have an API endpoint available that you can ping with the filter data and that can then generate the file and respond with the file URL.

1) Write a connected button component. This should have a mapStateToProps method to access the current filter data

https://marmelab.com/admin-on-rest/List.html#actions

2) It should also dispatch an action that generates a POST request.

https://marmelab.com/admin-on-rest/Actions.html#using-a-custom-action-creator

IMPORTANTLY: You will have to think about how the file itself will get downloaded. Since you are generating the URL on the fly, it will not be embedded in the model data so you do not have access to it. You might have to hard code a file name and path into your components so clicking will always lead to a download. Though this is not as trivial as it sounds, as the file generation itself will be an async operation. I think clicking this button should lead to a redirect to a page where the download link is displayed.

Answer (score 0):

Just to complement krunal's answer, there's a library called [FileSaver](https://github.com/eligrey/FileSaver.js/) that can take a json response and start a file save operation with its content, showing a file save dialog, or even download it directly to a file of your choice.